# How to render empty attributes in SSRS when exporting as XML with Report Data

Tags: reporting-services

I'm looking into exporting SSRS reports in XML format for someone and we've encountered a situation where the rendered table XML contains an element for every instance of the Details row but where any cell is empty, the attribute is not added to the element.

I'd much prefer to use the ATOM data feed output instead, as this is much more robust, however they're adamant about using the XML output.

Example output:

```
<Details DateStamp="2012-01-01" Customers="56703" Sales="624" />
<Details DateStamp="2012-02-01" />
<Details DateStamp="2012-03-01" Customers="107271" Sales="3195" />
```

Does anyone know of any way to force the output attributes to display, even if they have no value?  Or is this not possible in the XML format?

Ideally something like:

```
<Details DateStamp="2012-01-01" Customers="56703" Sales="624" />
<Details DateStamp="2012-02-01" Customer="" Sales="" />
<Details DateStamp="2012-03-01" Customers="107271" Sales="3195" />
```

Try this example query for a DataSet:

```
 SELECT
    '2012-01-01' as [DateStamp]
    ,56703 as [Customers]
    ,624 as [Sales]

UNION ALL

SELECT
    '2012-02-01' as [DateStamp]
    ,NULL as [Customers]
    ,NULL as [Sales]

UNION ALL

SELECT
    '2012-03-01' as [DateStamp]
    ,107271 as [Customers]
    ,3195 as [Sales]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each field in the Details row, set the property "DataElementOutput" to "Output." (This property is available in the properties pane when the field is selected.)

[Rendering Data in Report Builder and SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255251%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

In the dataset query, if you substitute the NULL value using ISNULL([ColName],0) or ISNULL([ColName],'') and combine this with DataElementOutput=Output, this would include all attributes for all rows in the xml.  It seems that the renderer treats NULLs as non-existant elements, rather than empty elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, setting the "DataElementOutput" property doesn't force empty fields to render data in the XML, it still displays as in my example above.

Comment: Hmmmm...It works in the example I'm working with. Are the empty fields contained in the dataset? Or do they exist only in the report? All fields should be included as part of the dataset, even if the field is always NULL or empty string. This would allow the DataElementOutput to always include all fields.

Comment: The fields exist in the DataSet definition, and are associated with the Tablix control (a table in my example). Any fields which have a NULL value (where other fields in the row have data) still don't show in the XML.  Viewing the report in-browser, they appear as blank cells in the table.  I've added an example query to show my dataset.

Comment: @GShenanigan When I tested it I used empty strings, and not NULL values. In the dataset query, can you use ISNULL(NULL,0) or ISNULL(NULL,''), where NULL would be replaced with the column name? With DataElementOutput=Output, this would include all attributes for all rows in the xml.

Comment: Okay, if I output all fields in my dataset as string values, and handle my NULLs, outputting empty strings, then the empty attributes render fine. However, if they're NULL, they won't render. I checked the generated HTML for the ReportViewer in my browser. Interestingly, it creates the table cells for the entries, but not the inner div.  This suggests that empty (i.e. NULL) items in a grouping don't get rendered at all, as it's treated like the entry itself doesn't exist at all, rather than the value of the entry is nothing.  So it sounds like the empty string/zero value is the only solution.